# Simplifying rspec unit tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

A lot of times in unit test in rspec having to specify both a context and a let is somewhat cumbersome and seems unnecessary.  For example:

```
context 'type = :invalid' do
  let(:type) { :invalid }

  it { expect { subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
end
```

It would be nicer (in aggregate over lots of tests) if I could do something like:

```
let_context type: :invalid do
  it { expect { subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
end
```

The method would define a context and let(s) for me and the context's argument would be something like `type = :invalid` or `let(:type) { :invalid }` because I don't have anything else to say other that the fact that this variable has changed.

Answer (score 1):

> > A lot of times in unit test in rspec having to specify both a context and a let is somewhat cumbersome

Sounds like you might want to use a [RSpec shared context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-context).

**UPDATE**

RSpec provides a DSL for the syntax you're suggesting: [a shared example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). For example:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "some thang" do |type|
 it { expect { subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
end

RSpec.shared_examples "a thang" do
  include_examples "some thang", :invalid
  # Or whatever is more appropriate for your domain
  # I.e., If you're testing subclass behavior use it_should_behave_like()
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at (and occasionally used) shared_context and it can be helpful, but in this case I'm talking about having one `it` for each `context` block (where each `context` block only defines one `let`).  What would be really nice and Englishy is something like when(type: :invalid) { expect { subject }.to raise_error }

Answer (score 0):

actually you could get less lines by following some http://betterspecs.org recommendations:

```
context 'type = :invalid' do
  let(:type) { :invalid }
  it { expect{ subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
end
```

Your variant could be read as

> it raises an error expect subject to raise error

While this is much cleaner

> it expect subject to raise_error

Nevertheless it is pretty off topic :)

**UPD**

Oh. Really you can't pass two blocks to method, so below example is not valid Ruby :)

```
context(:type) { :invalid } do
  it{ expect{ subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
end
```

While your example

```
let_context type: :invalid do
  ...
end
```

Won't do lazy execution, like `let` does

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  I actually switched some of my specs to using this sort of syntax.  That's definitely better, but doesn't answer the main question ;)

Comment: Edited the question based on this.  While I'm being picky: Why can't you use `expects`.  It would read so nice to say `it { expects { etc..`.  I think you can alias methods in the rspec config, so I might consider this ;)

Comment: @BrianUnderwood main reason why `let` lives separately from `context` is isolation. And in your case `let_context type: :invalid do` you are missing isolation. And second is laziness. It is very important requirements for testing. You don't want to get side effects which is hard to debug :)

Comment: True, what about `let_context type: -> { :invalid }`.  Starting to get a little less convenient, though

Comment: using procs/lambdas is very awkward solution :)